# Firebase Crashlytics CLI - generateid format

Tags: crashlytics, firebase-tools

According to the Firebase CLI reference, one can generate an xml file with the unique mapping id.
More information here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#crashlytics-commands

It looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!--
  This file is automatically generated by Crashlytics to uniquely
  identify the mapping file for your Android application.

  Do NOT modify or commit to source control!
-->
<string name="com_google_firebase_crashlytics_mapping_file_id" tools:ignore="UnusedResources,TypographyDashes" translatable="false">aed0116877954b13b3ac1c9841b22451</string>
</resources>
```

My question is - does the format of the value matter (`aed0116877954b13b3ac1c9841b22451` in this case)? Can it be, for example, an UUID format?